# Strange plot by using sklearn.linear_model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I typically use MATLAB, but want to push myself to learn something about Python. I tried a code of linear regression that introduced by a youtuber. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#read data
dataframe = pd.read_fwf('brain_body.txt')
x_values = dataframe[['Brain']]
y_values = dataframe[['Body']]

#train model on data
body_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
body_reg.fit(x_values,y_values)

#visualize results
plt.scatter(x_values,y_values)
plt.plot(x_values,body_reg.predict(x_values))
plt.show()
```

But I ended up with a very strange plot (I use Python 3.6):
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr8wV.jpg)

here is part of details:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIoxD.jpg)

Apparently, something is missing or wrong.

The data of brain_body.txt can be found in https://github.com/llSourcell/linear_regression_demo/blob/master/brain_body.txt

Any suggestion or advice is welcome.

***Update***

I tried sera's code, and here is what I get:
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2lTO.jpg)

It's funny and weird. it occurred to me that something is wrong with my data file, or something missing in my Python, but I just copied and pasted the raw data into the notepad and saved as .txt; I tried Python 3.6 and 2.7 as well as Pycharm and Spyder...so I have no idea...
BTW, the youtube video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOppzHpvTiQ&index=1&list=PL2-dafEMk2A7YdKv4XfKpfbTH5z6rEEj3)

@sascha @Moritz @sera I asked my friend to run the same code and data file, and everything is fine. In other words, there is something wrong with my Python and I don't know why. Let me try another computer and/or try an earlier version of python.

I tried, but nothing changed. Here are two different approaches I used to install Python:
1. Install Python (e.g. ver. 3.6); install Pycharm; install packages Pandas, scikit-learn...
2. Install Anaconda

***Solved***

Thanks for @Marc Bataillou 's suggestion. This is a problem associated with different versions of matplotlib. The problem was found in version 2.1.0. I tried 2.0.2 and found that the original code works fine in the older version; apparently, some changes are made from 2.0.2 to 2.1.0. Thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: ```plt.plot()``` will create lines between points. Your points = x_values are not sorted (not monotone).

Comment: @sascha I tried to sort the data and plot, but it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work is not enough to describe some approach and problem in detail.

Comment: you should do something like `xhat = np.linspace(min(x_values), max(x_values))` then `yhat = model.predict(xhat)` and finally `plt.plot(xhat, yhat)`

Comment: by the way, I would use the RANSAC regressor in this case: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RANSACRegressor.html#examples-using-sklearn-linear-model-ransacregressor

Comment: Push yourself :) I can recommend it. Walked the same path and do not regret it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 
plt.scatter(x_values.values,y_values.values) 
instead of 
plt.scatter(x_values,y_values)

I hope it works !

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It does work! However, one question still remains: Why other people can get the result just running the above code, but I need to add ".values"? Any idea?

Comment: I’m not sure but it may have something to do with a recent update of matplotlib, try asking your friend to run the code after updating the packages.

Comment: Thank you. I used matplotlib 2.1.0 and tried 2.0.2 just now, and found you're correct. The original code works fine in the older version; apparently, some changes from 2.0.2 to 2.1.0.

Answer (score -1):

You can visualize the results using the following code. I use cross validation for the predictions. If the model was perfect, then all the dots would be on the plotted line.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn import linear_model

#read data
dataframe = pd.read_fwf('brain_body.txt')

x_values = dataframe[['Brain']]
y_values = dataframe[['Body']]

#model on data
body_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# cross_val_predict returns an array of the same size as `y` where each entry
# is a prediction obtained by cross validation:
predicted = cross_val_predict(body_reg, x_values, y_values, cv=10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(y_values, predicted, edgecolors=(0, 0, 0))
ax.plot([y_values.min(), y_values.max()], [y_values.min(), y_values.max()], 'k--', lw=4)
ax.set_xlabel('Measured')
ax.set_ylabel('Predicted')
plt.show()
```

**Results**:

[image]

**Data**

https://ufile.io/p7x0r

Comment: Sera, thanks, I tried your code, but still don't get. Please find my result in the edited post.

Comment: i added the data, use the link and then use slow download after waiting 3 secs

Comment: I tried the data, but nothing changed. Let me uninstall all the stuffs and try.

Comment: yes please try to reinstall everything. where do you run the code ? are you on windows ?

Comment: i can produce the same plot in pycharm. where are you running the code ?

Comment: The problem is still there. Yes, I run in Win 7 (64 bit). Could you tell me what package/software you use and what result you will get if you just run the original code? THX.

Comment: I used both PyCharm and my terminal to run the code. In all cases, I get the same results as I posted in my answer. Python version 2.7.13